# How to use Ansible Python API to run ansible task

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-api

I would like to use Ansible 2.9.9 Python API to get config file and parse it to json format from servers in hosts file.

I don't know how to call an existing ansible task using Python API.
Through the Ansible API document, how to integrate ansible task with the sample code.

Sample.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import shutil
from ansible.module_utils.common.collections import ImmutableDict
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
from ansible.executor.task_queue_manager import TaskQueueManager
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase
from ansible import context
import ansible.constants as C

class ResultCallback(CallbackBase):
    """A sample callback plugin used for performing an action as results come in

    If you want to collect all results into a single object for processing at
    the end of the execution, look into utilizing the ``json`` callback plugin
    or writing your own custom callback plugin
    """
    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result, **kwargs):
        """Print a json representation of the result

        This method could store the result in an instance attribute for retrieval later
        """
        host = result._host
        print(json.dumps({host.name: result._result}, indent=4))

# since the API is constructed for CLI it expects certain options to always be set in the context object
context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(connection='local', module_path=['/to/mymodules'], forks=10, become=None,
                                become_method=None, become_user=None, check=False, diff=False)

# initialize needed objects
loader = DataLoader() # Takes care of finding and reading yaml, json and ini files
passwords = dict(vault_pass='secret')

# Instantiate our ResultCallback for handling results as they come in. Ansible expects this to be one of its main display outlets
results_callback = ResultCallback()

# create inventory, use path to host config file as source or hosts in a comma separated string
inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources='localhost,')

# variable manager takes care of merging all the different sources to give you a unified view of variables available in each context
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)

# create data structure that represents our play, including tasks, this is basically what our YAML loader does internally.
play_source =  dict(
        name = "Ansible Play",
        hosts = 'localhost',
        gather_facts = 'no',
        tasks = [
            dict(action=dict(module='shell', args='ls'), register='shell_out'),
            dict(action=dict(module='debug', args=dict(msg='{{shell_out.stdout}}')))
         ]
    )

# Create play object, playbook objects use .load instead of init or new methods,
# this will also automatically create the task objects from the info provided in play_source
play = Play().load(play_source, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)

# Run it - instantiate task queue manager, which takes care of forking and setting up all objects to iterate over host list and tasks
tqm = None
try:
    tqm = TaskQueueManager(
              inventory=inventory,
              variable_manager=variable_manager,
              loader=loader,
              passwords=passwords,
              stdout_callback=results_callback,  # Use our custom callback instead of the ``default`` callback plugin, which prints to stdout
          )
    result = tqm.run(play) # most interesting data for a play is actually sent to the callback's methods
finally:
    # we always need to cleanup child procs and the structures we use to communicate with them
    if tqm is not None:
        tqm.cleanup()

    # Remove ansible tmpdir
    shutil.rmtree(C.DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP, True)
```

sum.yml : generated summary file for each host

```
- hosts: staging
  tasks:
    - name: pt_mysql_sum
      shell: PTDEST=/tmp/collected;mkdir -p $PTDEST;cd /tmp;wget percona.com/get/pt-mysql-summary;chmod +x pt*;./pt-mysql-summary -- --user=adm --password=***** > $PTDEST/pt-mysql-summary.txt;cat $PTDEST/pt-mysql-summary.out;
      register: result
      environment:
        http_proxy: http://proxy.example.com:8080
        https_proxy: https://proxy.example.com:8080
    - name: ansible_result
      debug: var=result.stdout_lines
    - name: fetch_log
      fetch:
        src: /tmp/collected/pt-mysql-summary.txt
        dest: /tmp/collected/pt-mysql-summary-{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt
        flat: yes
```

hosts file

```
[staging]
vm1 ansible_ssh_host=10.40.50.41 ansible_ssh_user=testuser ansible_ssh_pass=*****
```